# Adding third party online basemap in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap

I am trying to figure out the coastline changes between past and present using map of a Japanese web page, something like Google Earth.

Is there any way I can import the basemap of an online web page into ArcMap so that I can trace the coastline to compare if there are any changes between past and present?

Comment: What is the website so we can see it if it has English version  that we may help you.

Answer (score 2):

[ArcBruTile](https://github.com/ArcBruTile/ArcBruTile) is useful to connect to a standard tile server XYZ/TMS:

> ArcBruTile displays a collection of maps in ArcGIS Pro 2.0 and ArcMap
>   10.0 - 10.6

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any chance I can use this on QGIS?
I just converted to QGIS recently

Answer (score 2):

QGIS NATIVELY supports XYZ TILE SERVERS URLS just add them or get plugin if you wish several plugins.are available